# Spring autoGrowNestedPaths not working

Tags: spring-mvc, collections

I have a List of objects with nested properties and at the bottom of the hierarchy each object has a CommonsMultipartFile property.

A *Folder* has a list of *Requisites* and each of those has a list of *Pages*

These are the bean definitions, each in its own file:

```
Page {
    private CommonsMultipartFile attributes;
    // Getter & Setter        
}

Requisite {       
    private List<Page> pages;
    // Other properties and Getters & Setters
}

Folder {
    private List<Requisite> requisites;
    // Getter & Setter
}
```

Then I add a Folder object to my modelMap inside a Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "loadFiles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initFiles(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Folder folder = new Folder();
    folder.setRequisites(requisitesModel.getRequisitesFromDB());
    model.addAttribute("folder", folder);
    return "loadFiles";
}
```

At this point the model attribute "folder" has a list of Requisite objects with various properties initialized, however pages (List`<Page>`) is null in all of them. This approach works fine and allows the user to load a bunch of files and the post request works as expected.

Then I added a method to handle a MaxUploadSizeExceededException and in the **resolveException** method I copied the behavior of the controller described above. This is to redirect the user to the same form when the total filesize exeeds a given threshold.

Here is the definition of the resolveException method:

```
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
    response, Object handler, Exception exception) {
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    Folder folder = new Folder();
    folder.setRequisites(requisitesModel.getRequisitesFromDB());
    model.addAttribute("error", "The files exceed the maximum filesize");
    model.addAttribute("folder", folder);
    return new ModelAndView("loadFiles", model);
}
```

The problem is that in this one the autoGrowNestedPaths does not work because immediately throws **Invalid property 'requisites[0].pages[0]' of bean class [mypackage.Folder]: Cannot access indexed value of property referenced in indexed property path 'pages[0]': returned null**.

My understanding is that spring by default autogrows nested paths for all Collection types, even without the use of LazyList or AutopopulatingList. Is my understanding wrong? Do I need to add something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I had and solved this problem myself, Jorge.**

WebDataBinder *does* default to auto-grow nested paths; and that includes collections.

But the interesting thing, is that this depends on getting the 'generic type' of the Collection from the property getter method. It uses reflection -- calling `Method.getGenericReturnType()`, which returns a java.lang.reflect.Type.

If it works, you get a java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType with the element-type of the collection, to grow;  if it doesn't, Spring will get a 'null' element-type & won't auto-grow.

See `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.growCollectionIfNecessary()`.

**In my case, Hibernate proxy (subclasses) were found not to have the requisite generic type & method-signature info.. even though this info was on the entity classes (when used directly!)**

I de-proxied the entity in my form controller "loadEntity" setup, and was right as rain. (De-proxying is useful & necessary in Hibernate apps sometimes, as are other proxy checks, comparisons, and manipulations.)

Code sample:

```
public static <T>  T deproxy (T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return obj;
    if (obj instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        // Unwrap Proxy;
        //      -- loading, if necessary.
        HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy) obj;
        LazyInitializer li = proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
        return (T)  li.getImplementation();
    } 
    return obj;
}

public static boolean isProxy (Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof HibernateProxy)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static boolean isSame (Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == o2)
        return true;
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) 
        return false;
    Object d1 = deproxy(o1);
    Object d2 = deproxy(o2);
    if (d1 == d2)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static Class getClassWithoutInitializingProxy (Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy) obj;
        LazyInitializer li = proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
        return li.getPersistentClass();
    } 
    // Not a Proxy.
    return obj.getClass();
}
```

Hope this helps guide you to your problem.. give me an upvote even!

Comment: Hi Thomas,I have a similar case where I get index out of bounds while binding an arraylist.Do you mean using proper generic type for my list would solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @RVP -- yes. See BeanWrapperImpl.growCollectionIfNecessary(), it's always useful to attach the sources to your project in the IDE. In Eclipse I just press Ctrl-Shift-T and bring up BeanWrapperImpl..

Comment: And.. if you look at the source.. growCollectionIfNecessary() uses GenericCollectionTypeResolver, and that can't find the specific type, then no element is added & the collection can not be grown. This is all silent internally, no logging or exceptions, so it's tricky to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

From the [BeanWrapper javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html)

> **setAutoGrowNestedPaths**
>
> void setAutoGrowNestedPaths(boolean
> autoGrowNestedPaths)
>
> Set whether this BeanWrapper should attempt to "auto-grow" a nested
> path that contains a null value.  If "true", a null path location will
> be populated with a default object value and traversed instead of
> resulting in a NullValueInNestedPathException. Turning this flag on
> also enables auto-growth of collection elements when accessing an
> out-of-bounds index.
>
> Default is "false" on a plain BeanWrapper.

So no, `BeanWrapperImpl` does not autogrow nested path for lists by default (assuming you are using spring 3). Like you mentioned in your post, you can fix this by using an Autopopulating or Lazy list.
You can also use initbinder to exlicitely set autogrowNestedPaths property to true.

Comment: But I'm not using BeanWrapper, I'm using WebDataBinder `@InitBinder public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true); }` And in the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setAutoGrowNestedPaths%28boolean%29) states Autogrow is true by default